# tracking all selections of multiple choice questions in qualtrics using javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am having to design a study using Qualtrics and need to track every selection of each multiple-choice question response. I need all the questions to remain on one page as timing logic is being used for submission.

I tried using a click event but it records all clicks on the screen and only gives me a clickcount. I was hoping to modify it to track the responses until I realized it only tracks clicks no matter where. Code tried below:

```
**this.questionclick = function(event, element) {
if(element.type == "radio") {
var n = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData('n');
n = n + 1;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('n', n);}
}**
```

I then found a way to insert logic based on an event in Qualtrics itself, but it doesn't appear to be working. I still only get the final response and an overall click count.
Here is the event logic I tried under actions in Qualtrics. It gives me a click count and the final response rather than every response selected.
[Image of event logic in Qualtrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhMa3.png)
I am new to programming and no nothing about javascript. Can someone help me track every selection of each question? I plan to have 30 questions or so, but the questions are not finalized yet.